# GCP CDN - server requests return a 404

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

I followed the guide to set up [an external global, app engine based, load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-serverless). I linked it to Google's CDN by ticking the little box in the LB configuration settings.

Now, when I load my domain name, it says `CANNOT GET /`. The request returns a 404, along with some `C S P: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“default-src”).` error messages.

It was working well before adding the CDN. So, I'm assuming my app server configuration is fine.
In the Load Balancer details, there is a little chart under the Monitoring section, with how traffic flows.
It shows traffic coming from the 3 global regions, going to the frontend of the LB, then to `/ (unknown)` and `/ (unmatched)` as `URL Rule`, then to the backend service I defined, and finally to a backend instance labelled `NO_BACKEND_SELECTED`.

I'm guessing the issue comes either from the `URL Rule` or `Backend Instance`, but there is little in the doc. to troubleshoot.
I followed the doc. to setup the LB. Settings are pretty simple using App Engine, so there is little room for wrong doing. But I may have missed something still.
In the 'create serverless NEG', I did select App Engine, and `default` as the service name (although i'm not sure what `default` actually means).

Any idea what's missing ?

EDIT :

So, in the load balancing menu, I go to the 'Backends' section at the top, and select my backend. Here I have the list of 'General properties' of my backend. Except, under 'Backends', it says the following : ***Backends contain instance groups of VMs or network endpoint groups. This backend service has no backends yet edit***

From there, I can click the edit link, which redirects me to the 'Backend service edit' menu. I DO have a backend selected in there. I did create a serverless NEG using App Engine.

So, what's missing ? Is there anything wrong with Google's serverless backend ?

Answer (score 1):

I wanna help you with the issue that you are facing.

### [If the responses from your external backend are not cached by Cloud CDN](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/troubleshooting-ext-https-lbs#responses_from_my_external_backend_are_not_cached_by)

Ensure that:

-You have enabled Cloud CDN on the backend service containing the NEG that points to your external backend by setting enableCDN to true. **(DONE as per your description).**

-Responses served by your external backend meet Cloud CDN caching requirements. For example, you are sending `Cache-Control: public, max-age=3600` response headers from the origin.

### [The current implementation of Cloud CDN stores responses in cache if all of the following are true.](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/caching#cacheability)

***Attribute:***
Served by

***Requirement:***
Backend service, backend bucket, or an external backend with Cloud CDN enabled

---

***Attribute:***
In response to

***Requirement:***
GET request

---

***Attribute:***
Status code

***Requirement:***
*200, 203, 204, 206, 300, 301, 302, 307, 308, 404, 405, 410, 421, 451, or 501.*

---

***Attribute:***
Freshness

***Requirement:***
The response has a *Cache-Control* header with a *max-age* or *s-maxage* directive, or an Expires header with a timestamp in the future.

For cacheable responses without an age (for example, with no-cache), the public directive must be explicitly provided.

With the *CACHE_ALL_STATIC* cache mode, if no freshness directives are present, a successful response with static content type is still eligible for caching.

With the *FORCE_CACHE_ALL* cache mode, any successful response is eligible for caching.

If negative caching is enabled and the status code matches one for which negative caching specifies a TTL, the response is eligible for caching, even without explicit freshness directives.

---

***Attribute:***
Content

***Requirement:***
Contains a valid Content-Length, Content-Range, or Transfer-Encoding: chunked header.

For example, a Content-Length header that correctly matches the size of the response.

---

***Attribute:***
Size

***Requirement:***
Less than or equal to the maximum size.
For responses with sizes between 10 MB and 5 TB, see the additional cacheability constraints described in byte range requests.

---

### [Please validate the URL Mapping too:](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-url-rewrite#modifying_the_url_map)

This is an example as reference adapt this according your project.

1. Create a YAML file `/tmp/http-lb.yaml`, making sure to substitute `PROJECT_ID` with your project ID.

When a user requests path `/*`, the path gets rewritten in the backend to the actual location of the content, which is `/love-to-fetch/*`.

```
defaultService: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/global/backendBuckets/cats
hostRules:
- hosts:
  - '*'
  pathMatcher: path-matcher-1
name: http-lb
pathMatchers:
- defaultService: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/global/backendBuckets/cats
  name: path-matcher-1
  pathRules:
  - paths:
    - /*
    routeAction:
      urlRewrite:
        pathPrefixRewrite: /love-to-fetch/
    service: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/global/backendBuckets/dogs
tests:
- description: Test routing to backend bucket, dogs
  host: example.com
  path: /love-to-fetch/test
  service: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/global/backendBuckets/dogs
```

2. Validate the URL map.

```
gcloud compute url-maps validate --source /tmp/http-lb.yaml
```

If the tests pass and the command outputs a success message, save the changes to the URL map.

3. Update the URL map.

```
gcloud compute url-maps import http-lb \
   --source /tmp/http-lb.yaml \
   --global
```

### [Using URL maps](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/url-map)